# Install db-oracle for node js

Tags: oracle, node.js

While I try to install db-oracle for node js in Terminal of mac OS. Getting the below error.
Please help.

The error list I get is as follows on npm install db-oracle

unameits-Mac-mini:InstantClient vinod$ npm install db-oracle npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/db-oracle npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/db-oracle

db-oracle@0.2.3 install /usr/InstantClient/node_modules/db-oracle node-waf configure build

Checking for program g++ or c++ : /usr/bin/g++

Checking for program cpp : /usr/bin/cpp

Checking for program ar : /usr/bin/ar

Checking for program ranlib : /usr/bin/ranlib

Checking for g++ : ok

Checking for node path : not found

Checking for node prefix : ok /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.8.11

Checking for header occi.h : Missing include files for OCI

/usr/InstantClient/node_modules/db-oracle/wscript:42: error: the configuration failed (see '/usr/InstantClient/node_modules/db-oracle/build/config.log')

db-oracle@0.2.3 preuninstall /usr/InstantClient/node_modules/db-oracle rm -rf build/*

npm ERR! db-oracle@0.2.3 install: node-waf configure build

npm ERR! sh "-c" "node-waf configure build" failed with 1

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the db-oracle@0.2.3 install script.

npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the db-oracle package,

npm ERR! not with npm itself.

npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:

npm ERR! node-waf configure build

npm ERR! You can get their info via:

npm ERR! npm owner ls db-oracle

npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Darwin 11.3.0

npm ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.8.11/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "db-oracle"

npm ERR! cwd /usr/InstantClient

npm ERR! node -v v0.8.11

npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.62

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:

npm ERR! /usr/InstantClient/npm-debug.log

npm ERR! not ok code 0

Comment: What are the contents of /usr/InstantClient/node_modules/db-oracle/build/config.log?

Comment: The same contents as displayed here. Can you help with this?

Answer (score 1):

here is the cricial part of the logs:

`Checking for header occi.h : Missing include files for OCI`

To fix it, you need to set OCI_INCLUDE_DIR and OCI_LIB_DIR env variables

Assuming that oracle client and sdk are installed in **/opt/instantclient**

```
$ export OCI_INCLUDE_DIR=/opt/instantclient/sdk/include/ 
$ export OCI_LIB_DIR=/opt/instantclient
```

Then just install the module.

Comment: Hi I came across a similar error but after correctly installing oracledb package, then running meteor run it gives an error about oracledb again missing modules - `../build/Release/oracledb` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45105846/how-to-resolve-unable-to-resolve-some-modules-oracledb