# How to resolve "Unable to resolve some modules oracledb"?

Tags: node.js, oracle, meteor, node-oracledb

I've setup a meteor project and imported the [oracledb node package](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb).
But after starting the project via `meteor run` I get a console build error. Stating that `Unable to resolve some modules`.

Machine setup:

Windows 7 x64

- node v6.9.1 x64
- npm 3.10.9 x64
- instaclient sdk and basic x86
- C++ redistributables

[image]

To debug the issue I've:

- Followed the debug steps in this issue - [Unable to resolve some modules in Meteor 1.4.1.1](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/516)
- checked that the package exists in node_modules which it does:

**Question:**

How can you resolve "Unable to resolve some modules oracledb" during a meteor run?

Environment Variables are set and directory exists:

**OCI ENV vars -**

[image]

**Path var-**

[image]

**Directory location of Oracle instaclient**

[image]

[image: node_modules]

Error log during `meteor run`:

```
$ meteor run
[[[[[ C:\Users\derp\Documents\Projects\dmo-progam-site ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> A patch (Meteor 1.4.1.3) for your current release is available!
   Update this project now with 'meteor update --patch'.
=> Started MongoDB.

Unable to resolve some modules:

  "../build/Release/oracledb" in
/C/Users/derp/Documents/Projects/dmo-progam-site/node_modules/oracledb/lib/oracledb.js
(os.windows.x86_32)
  "../build/Debug/oracledb" in
/C/Users/derp/Documents/Projects/dmo-progam-site/node_modules/oracledb/lib/oracledb.js
(os.windows.x86_32)

=> Started your app.

=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
```

Comment: do you have the file oracledb.js inside lib folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that basic node-oracledb [examples](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/tree/master/examples) run outside Meteor.  This will confirm that node-oracledb is installed and able to find the Oracle client libraries and MS VS Redistributable.  Make sure the architectures (32-bit or 64-bit) of Node, Oracle client libraries, and the Redistributable all match.

Comment: Hey so I tried installing oracledb into a test folder and it installed fine. When I run my other project the install runs fine also but..this project seems to be looking for x86 arc according to the error it throws during meteor run?

`Unable to resolve some modules:

  "../build/Release/oracledb" in
/C/Users/varleyb/Documents/Projects/dmo-progam-site/node_modules/oracledb/lib/or
acledb.js
(os.windows.x86_32)`

Comment: Are you saying one is 64 bit and the other 32 bit?  Do you have the right Oracle client library architecture for the one Meteor is using?

Comment: Yes I have the correct x86 instaclient that the meteor project is looking for. I added more info to my question above. When I tried to install your node-oracledb repository I get a build error during `oracledb` install. Any ideas what to look at reading my log above?

Comment: You don't have the right Oracle client libraries in your PATH.   All those missing OCI* symbols are part of the Oracle client.

Comment: ok by right Oracle client libraries which version are you referring to?
I've verified the path `OCI_LIB_DIR` and `OCI_INC_DIR` are set, also `C:\Oracle\instantclient;` exists in my PATH environment variable.

Comment: I went over the installation of OracleDB for my project with the correct instaclient and c++ dlls. The package now installs and project runs as expected with connector to Oracle DB instance. The warning below still shows during build but it seems to be spurious - `Unable to resolve some modules:

  "../build/Release/oracledb" in
/C/Users/derp/Documents/Projects/dmo-progam-site/node_modules/oracledb/lib/oracledb.js
(os.windows.x86_32)
  "../build/Debug/oracledb" in
/C/Users/derp/Documents/Projects/dmo-progam-site/node_modules/oracledb/lib/oracledb.js
(os.windows.x86_32)`

Comment: In addition to the above, I deleted my node_modules from the project. Then opened Node.js `ia32 bash` and `meteor npm install`. The key seemed to be running the npm install from 32bit node. You will need to install node.js 32bit to have that terminal available on your machine.

Answer (score 1):

We had someone report this before but I couldn't reproduce. Please look through the steps I used here to see if they help: https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/516#issuecomment-267480686